# Do electrons always re-emit photons of a lower wavelength after absorption?

Tags: energy-conservation, electrons, atomic-physics, quantum-electrodynamics

Just a short little question: When an electron falls back down to a ground state from an excited state, will it always dissipate some of that energy as heat resulting in a lower energy photon being emitted?

Comment: Why do you think the electron "dissipates energy as heat"?

Comment: So, it doesn't dissipate energy as heat when it settles down into its groundstate?

Comment: In an atomic system, no. In, say, a semiconductor system one can promote an electron from the valence band into the conduction band above the band edge. This will generally result in the electron losing energy (ultimately in to heat) to settle near the conduction band edge. Recombination would then give a lower energy photon. But, the solid system has additional degrees of freedom available to it that the isolated atomic system does not.

Comment: There's another mechanism though: The absorption and re-emission of a photon induces a small electric dipole in the atom which, in turn, can generate phonons. Your question, as I understand it, could therefore be reframed as 'does a photon-phonon coupling mechanism *always* exist in, say, a crystal?' Which seems like a valid and interesting question.

Comment: I think answer is no, if you consider electron in a crystal.  See for example http://www.nature.com/nphoton/journal/v4/n3/full/nphoton.2009.269.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it demonstrates no research effort

Answer (score 3):

It depends.

If you're dealing with an isolated atom then when the atom relaxes it emits a photon with the same energy as the one it absorbed. That's because there isn't anywhere else for the energy to go.

However if you're dealing with a solid or a liquid the excited state can transfer some of the energy into lattice vibrations i.e. heat, then it can emit a photon with a lower energy. This is what happens in [fluorescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescence) and [phosphorescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorescence).

So the answer is that no it won't **always** dissipate some of that energy as heat, but there are indeed circumstances in which this can happen.